# How to tell CRAN to install package dependencies automatically?

Tags: r, cran, r-forge

I develop a package in R and when I check and build it in my local computer it works properly. But when I tried it in CRAN, I get a package dependencies error. My package depends on two functions of other packages.

If I list the other packages under the `description` using `Depends` or `imports`, will it be automatically installed with the new package? Or do I need to explicitly invoke the function `install.packages("packagename")` under the function that I've used the other packages. if this all is wrong, what is the best way to solve package dependencies in `R` inorder to pass the `R CMD check` and `build` test and submit to CRAN?

Thank you.

Comment: yes, list the other packages after `Depends:` in your `DESCRIPTION` file

Comment: An easy test to use is to remove package `X` from your system and see if your package installs `X` from the Depends.

Answer (score 91):

On your own system, try

```
install.packages("foo", dependencies=...)
```

with the `dependencies=` argument is documented as

```
dependencies: logical indicating to also install uninstalled packages
      which these packages depend on/link to/import/suggest (and so
      on recursively).  Not used if ‘repos = NULL’.  Can also be a
      character vector, a subset of ‘c("Depends", "Imports",
      "LinkingTo", "Suggests", "Enhances")’.

      Only supported if ‘lib’ is of length one (or missing), so it
      is unambiguous where to install the dependent packages.  If
      this is not the case it is ignored, with a warning.

      The default, ‘NA’, means ‘c("Depends", "Imports",
      "LinkingTo")’.

      ‘TRUE’ means (as from R 2.15.0) to use ‘c("Depends",
      "Imports", "LinkingTo", "Suggests")’ for ‘pkgs’ and
      ‘c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo")’ for added
      dependencies: this installs all the packages needed to run
      ‘pkgs’, their examples, tests and vignettes (if the package
      author specified them correctly).
```

so you probably want a value `TRUE`.

In your package, list what is needed in `Depends:`, see the 
[Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual which is pretty clear on this.

Comment: @ dirk, thanks. But now I've got where the problem is occurred. When I run `R CMD check` on `R-forge` it has a package dependency error with `linux-x86-64` platform. but there was no error for `windows` and `mac ` OS. the error message looks like this:   `using platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)  
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Packages required but not available:
  ‘isa2’ ‘fabia’`

Comment: ... and what if I removed a package? I would like to remove all its dependencies as long as they are not required by some other already installed packages?

Comment: @andi: it's often not that simple. Installation of dependencies can fail, if they require compilation on your platform (or if the version that CRAN insists on downloading is source, even though binary distributions may be available elsewhere). *xgboost* used to be notorious for this, for example.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to select the Install Dependencies checkbox  In the R package installer, on the bottom right:

[image]