# Loading R packages from custom library locations when there's no read/write access to default library location

Tags: r, package, read-write

We use R at my university, where all computers run Windows XP or Windows 7 and read/write access to most places on the C drive is disabled. This includes the default directory for downloading and installing R packages, but does not include the Downloads folder, so I've been using this work-around:

```
install.packages("plyr",lib="C:/Users/g-rde434/Downloads/")
library(plyr,lib.loc="C:/Users/g-rde434/Downloads/")
```

where `g-rde434` is the username and I'm just using `plyr` as an example. For packages that require a lot of other packages in order to work, this gets messy because I've found that I have to manually install all the depends before I can install the package I actually want to use. For instances, packages like `ggplot2` and `sirt` each require a whole bunch of other packages to work properly. Is there a much easier way to do what I'm trying to do? I'm not asking about clever vectorizing tricks or anything like that, but rather some way to force the "higher-up" packages (e.g., `ggplot2` or `sirt`) to load all the other packages it needs from the library location I specified above?

Comment: Might this help: `install.packages("plyr", lib="C:/Users/g-rde434/Downloads/", dependencies=TRUE)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171148/how-to-tell-cran-to-install-package-dependencies-automatically

Comment: R, at least on Linux, if it can't write to the system library asks me if I want to create a personal library (in $HOME/R/...), and then all the dependencies go there too. Not true for Windows? What version of R?

Comment: Spacedman's answer should apply to Windows, as well. Try something like: `.libPaths('C:/Users/g-rde434/Downloads/')`

Comment: I'll try the dependencies argument tomorrow (no access til then). @Spacedman we're on R 3.0.2. Thanks all for the suggestions.

Comment: @majom Yup, that did it -- thanks! If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Great. I have posted an answer. Perhaps it be might useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
install.packages("plyr", lib="C:/Users/g-rde434/Downloads/", dependencies=TRUE)
```

For further reference see:
[How to tell CRAN to install package dependencies automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171148/how-to-tell-cran-to-install-package-dependencies-automatically)