# Writing R package, trimTrees and kknn cannot be installed automatically

Tags: r, dependencies, package, r-forge

Recently my [package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=2010) on R-Forge failed to build on windows, not linux. Apparently packages kknn and trimTrees are not available. I cannot figure out why or why these two packages are different from randomForest or rgl which installs automatically. I have tried to include package names in description file in Depends-field and/or in Imports-field. Nothing works... 
If installing my package from r-forge repos, with randomForest and trimTrees package removed, first mentioned will install automatically second will fail and have to be installed manually first. Why is this?

I have already read the this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171148/how-to-tell-cran-to-install-package-dependencies-automatically#_=_)

thanks alot, Soren

description file:

```
 Package: forestFloor
 Type: Package
 Title: forestFloor
 Version: 1.4
 Date: 2015-05-19
 Author: Soeren Havelund Welling
 Maintainer: Soeren Havelund Welling <SOWE@DTU.DK>
 Depends: R (>= 3.0.0), randomForest, trimTrees, rgl, kknn
 Suggests:
 Description: Visualizes Random Forrest with feature contributions.
 SystemRequirements: OpenGL, GLU Library, zlib
 License: GPL-2
 Imports: Rcpp (>= 0.11.3), randomForest, trimTrees, rgl, kknn 
 LinkingTo: Rcpp
```

namespace

```
 useDynLib(forestFloor)

 importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
 importFrom(randomForest, randomForest)
 importFrom(trimTrees, cinbag)
 import(rgl)
 import(kknn)

 S3method(plot,forestFloor)
 S3method(print,forestFloor)
 export(forestFloor,
        plot.forestFloor,
        print.forestFloor,
        box.outliers,
        recTree,
        vec.plot,
        convolute_ff,
        convolute_ff2,
        convolute_grid,
        show3d_new,
        fcol,
        randomForest,
        plot3d,
        kknn,
        persp3d)
```

-----------log file from r forge ----------

- using log directory 'R:/run/building/build_2015-05-19-12-04/RF_PKG_CHECK/PKGS/forestFloor.Rcheck'
- using R version 3.2.0 Patched (2015-05-16 r68378)
- using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
- using session charset: ISO8859-1
- using option '--as-cran'
- checking for file 'forestFloor/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
- checking extension type ... Package
- this is package 'forestFloor' version '1.4'
- checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE
  Maintainer: 'Soeren Havelund Welling '
  New submission

The Title field is just the package name: provide a real title.
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
  No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped

Packages required but not available: 'trimTrees' 'kknn'

See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual.
* DONE

Status: 1 ERROR, 1 NOTE
See
  'R:/run/building/build_2015-05-19-12-04/RF_PKG_CHECK/PKGS/forestFloor.Rcheck/00check.log'
for details.

Run time: 6.77 seconds.

Comment: btw fixed the title error mentioned in log file...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a current rForge server issue when it updated to R 3.2. The problem can for now be fixed manually by contacting admin. They're working on general fix also.

[link to bug tracker](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=194&aid=6101&group_id=34)