# Error while installing package kableExtra in R

Tags: r, r-package, kableextra

I am trying to install kableExtra and get the following errors:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = 
vI[[j]]) : 
there is no package called 'hms'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'kableExtra'

*removing 'C:/Users/Tim/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/kableExtra'
Warning in install.packages :
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.5/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Tim\Documents\R\win-library\3.2"      
C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUJQfwD/downloaded_packages/kableExtra_0.9.0. 
 tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘kableExtra’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUJQfwD\downloaded_packages’
```

How can I solve my problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

it seems kableExtra depends on the package "hms" so try install it before with:

```
install.packages("hms")
```

or via rstudio interface:
packages -> install
and type in "hms"

also try this command:

```
install.packages("kableExtra", dependencies = TRUE)
```

If there appear problems like installing `rlang` or something similar, there is no general solution for this. You can try to (re)install `rtools`. Sometimes there are missing parts of r installations. My guess if R can't install a dependencie is, that some library or tools of the R environment are missing or wrongly installed which have to be detected.

Comment: Then I get the information that 'rlang' is not available for package 'hms' and I can't install 'rlang'

Comment: Why can't you install `rlang`?

Comment: you could also try:
install.packages("kableExtra", dependencies = TRUE)
this will install all dependent packages und suggestions, though it could not work with your error of installing rlang. But worth a try

Answer (score 0):

You have a trouble with the dependency with the package "hms". I have not got how you are installing the r package, but you can either install it first and then try it again or start the installation with the option of download and install all required dependencies, in the second option you need to be online and allow the package manager to intall what is required.

Here is how it looks in RGui. I guess your are not using RGui.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Then I get the following errors:                                                                     ERROR: dependency 'rlang' is not available for package 'hms'
* removing 'C:/Users/Tim/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/hms'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.5/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Tim\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiCcuL8/downloaded_packages/hms_0.4.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: The list of dependencies could be quite large. Have a look to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171148/how-to-tell-cran-to-install-package-dependencies-automatically

Comment: you have not said too much about your system and enviroment.

Comment: I tried RGui now but it isn't working with the same error: 'ERROR: dependency 'rlang' is not available for package 'hms' ' when I try to install hms.