# Trouble Installing and Calling R Package

Tags: r

I am trying to install the R package "rattle".

I do so by simply typing:

```
install.packages("rattle")
```

...upon which a lot of good installin' seems to take place. But then when I call the package

```
library(rattle)
```

I get the error message

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rattle’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘stringi’

All of the research I've done online suggests some form of

```
install.packages("rattle", insert_something_here)
```

but I've had no luck with such methods.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172931/6666231) may help.

Comment: Search the log for any errors/warnings. There may be missing libraries, other system software. Try install.packages("stringi"). Provide more details on OS, environment.

Comment: `install.packages("rattle", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have tried that, thank you. I'll give it another go, though. Could me repeatedly installing this package without uninstalling it be a problem?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 through R Studio.

Comment: @ytu Thank you, I believe that answer was suggesting MauritsEvers suggestion, which has not worked for me.

Comment: @P.May The error suggests that dependencies are not met. `install.packages` with `dependencies = TRUE` should take care of that; or alternatively manually `install.packages("stringi")`. Were there additional errors/warnings when you did `install.packages("rattle", dependencies = TRUE)`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers On my honor, I  promise I have tried both of those things. I'm giving them another go now, though.

Comment: @P.May Hmm. I had a quick look at the CRAN vignette: *"The first thing to ensure is that you have installed the GTK+ libraries and the GGobi application. This is operating system dependent and full installation instructions are available from http://rattle.togaware.com/"*. Did you follow these instructions?

Comment: I looked on that website, but I could not find instructions more in-depth than install.packages("rattle")

Comment: When I attempt to install stringi manually, I get the errors/warning in the log: ERROR: compilation failed for package 'stringi'
* removing 'C:/Users/SnacksOnSnacksz/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/stringi'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: So I'm looking at the folder where my packages are installing, and I can see all of the needed packages there except for "stringi". When I manually install "stringi", a 
stringi folder is created for the duration of the installation and then promptly disappears when the installation is complete. This seems to be the problem, but I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: @P.May I think there are two issues here: You need to manually install the GTK+ libraries and GGobi *first*; see e.g. [here](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) for instructions involving the former, and [here](http://www.ggobi.org/downloads/) for the latter. *Then* work out why the installation of `stringi` is failing. You should include critical details and updates in your main post (not in comments).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the entire issue seemed to revolve around the stringi package.

I first installed the latest Rtools package from

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

and then I was able to successfully install stringi manually

```
install.packages("stringi")
```

and then I could call `rattle` no problem.